# Creating SQLite Virtual Table with EF context.Database.EnsureCreated?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Would be possible to create SQLite Virtual Table using EF Core `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`? I would expect something like `[Virtual]` attribute to the respective model class.

The reason for this question is using free text search (FTS) for SQLite in-memory DB which requires virtual table. I understand that I can use runtime migrations but EnsureCreated() is so neat and convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be not possible using `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`directly for such specifics but a runtime migration works just fine. I only had to replace this line with very similar `context.Database.Migrate()` (having migration already in the project, of course) and that's it.